# Java console loop

Tags: java, joptionpane

Noticed no one has answered this yet on here so thought I'd give it a shot again. Hopefully someone can help. Already went to my Java teacher and he just said I messed something up and couldn't figure it out so I can't move on.

Anywho, here's my test code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a real number");
    }
}
```

And this is what I receive in console:

```
hello
```

`03:30.28 1[dbg] In DllGetClassObject`
`03:30.28 2[dbg] CShellExtClassFactory::CShellExtClassFactory()`
`03:30.28 3[dbg] CShellExtClassFactory::QueryInterface()`
`03:30.28 4[dbg] CShellExtClassFactory::CreateInstance()`
`03:30.28 5[dbg] CShellExt::CShellExt()`
`03:30.28 6[dbg] Looping before Zumo is running`
`03:30.28 7[dbg] CShellExt::QueryInterface()==>IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier`
`03:30.28 8[dbg] CShellExt::AddRef()`
`03:30.28 9[dbg] CShellExt::AddRef()`
`03:30.28 10[dbg] CShellExt::Release()`
`03:30.28 11[dbg] CShellExt::QueryInterface()==>IID_IShellIconOverlayIdentifier`
`03:30.28 12[dbg] CShellExt::AddRef()`
`03:30.28 13[dbg] CShellExt::Release()`
`03:30.28 14[dbg] Entering CShellExt::GetOverlayInfo`
`03:30.28 15[dbg] Icon path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP CloudDrive\icons\deflated.ico`
`03:30.28 16[dbg] Exiting CShellExt::GetOverlayInfo successfully.`

Any help would greatly be appreciated. I have already tried re installing everything I could which include eclipse and the JDK 1.7. I also noticed this only happens when I try to use the dialog JOptionPane so far. I am using a windows 7 system.

Thanks guys

Comment: Works for me (Windows 7/Java 7/Eclipse)

Comment: Netbeans, Mac OS 10.7.5, Java 1.7, update 7 - All okay

Comment: Works for me too (Windows 7/Java 7/IntelliJ).

What is that JNI rubbish from HP CloudDrive? Is that related to the question?

Comment: Yeah, looks definitely strange.

Comment: This thread mentions a similar problem : http://area.autodesk.com/forum/autodesk-maya/installation---hardware---os/problems-with-output-window/page-last/ It seems uninstalling ZumoCast was the solution.

Comment: It's some HP branding BS, from the looks of it. But it shouldn't interfere.

Comment: Surprisingly, it did interfere :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, because I have ran into strange AWT/Swing issues on other systems, you could try this here (sometimes the underlying UI system gets not initialized properly, but as I said, this is just a guess):

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("hello");
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a real number");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

By using `invokeLater` you force the whole UI system to get initialized (the EDT to be started and the option pane showed from inside the EDT), I had to use this trick e.g. for getting my SDL bindings under OSX to work. `invokeLater` initializes the whole Cocoa system for me.

Comment: That certainly **should** be done, whether it solves this problem or not.

Comment: Guys I just wanted to say THANK YOU to everyone who replied because it was very fast as well as it helped me solve the situation. The solution ended up being a pre-installed software called Hp Cloud drive which is just a sub-title for the Zumo(same developers) After I uninstalled it, I do not get that horrendous mass of code. Everything works fine.// My suggestion to anyone having this problem is to check to see if you have a cloud software of some kind. Anyways thanks again everyone. I read every comment and used it in a trial and error process until I found the solution. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me too when I had a `JTextField` or `JTextArea` showing in my program. It only occurred when compiling and running on Java 7 or higher, but not on Java 6.

I don't know why it was happening, but uninstalling HP CloudDrive, a program which came pre-installed on my HP laptop, stopped all those lines showing up.